# OctoberCMS Minify disable

Tags: minify, octobercms

Does anyone know how to turn off Minify completely in OctoberCMS or WinterCMS?
i set the config / cms.php file but nothing changes.

Regards,
The Lacesz

Comment: Which minify are you talking about?

Comment: first let us know what minify, which files you need to stop minify, you can not turn off core minify (it requires much more effort to stop) so please share us what thing you want to stop minify